# 2.8 Beta Hotkeys for manipulators

Tags: customization

Is there any way to define hotkey for selecting manipulators in 2.8? I found one thread mentioning view3d.enable_manipulator command but that worked for 2.7.3, while https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/ does not mention enable_manipulator method so my guess is it got moved somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the view3d.enable_manipulator command appears to be disabled in Blender 2.8 beta.

The next best solution that I could find is changing the Spacebar Action in your preferences to "Tools".

[image: blender 2.8 beta preferences]

This will activate your tools menu when pressing the spacebar, allowing you to access the hotkeys for the manipulator.

[image: blender 2.8 beta 3d view w/ tools]

Answer (score 0):

You can also rightclick the tool in the toolbar and change the shortcut there. This won't save in your preferences though so you might wanna include that change into your startup file. It also must be changed for each mode seperately.
With already existing files I run into the problem that these shortcuts won't save at all and need to be redone at every load. 
This function overall feels very *beta version* but might be what you need for now.